# Symfony2 sudenly login route not found

Tags: php, symfony, exception, authentication

This morning i wrote some new functions on a controller and worked perfectly but after 10 minutes suddenly trying to get access to one of the methods Symfony says me: **"No route found for "GET /login"**, and even if I try to have access to app.php says to me the same exception.

In this project i use routing through @Route and through the routing.yml file

Below I'll show my configurations

## Routing's file

> **app/config/routing.yml**
>
> frab:
>       resource: "@FrabApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
>
> frab_routting:
>       resource: "@FrabApiBundle/Controller"
>       type:     annotation
>       prefix:   /
>
> fos_user_security:
>        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
>        prefix: admin
>         fos_user_profile:
>        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
>        prefix: /profile
>
> fos_user_register:
>       resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
>       prefix: /register
>
> fos_user_resetting:
>       resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
>       prefix: /resetting
>
> fos_user_change_password:
>       resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
>       prefix: /profile

## Security's file

> **app/config/security.yml**
>
> security:
>       encoders:
>           FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
>
> ```
> role_hierarchy:
>     ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
>     ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
>
> providers:
>     fos_userbundle:
>       id: fos_user.user_provider.username
>       id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
>
> firewalls:
>     dev:
>         pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
>         security: false
>
>     dashboard:
>         pattern:  ^/
>         security: true
>         form_login:
>             provider: fos_userbundle
>             check_path: /admin/login_check
>             login_path: /login
>             default_target_path: /ds
>             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
>         logout:
>             path: /ds/logout
>             target: /ds
>         anonymous: ~
>
> access_control:
>     - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds/groups, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds/photos, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds/mail, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/ds/sendmail, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
>     - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
> ```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You've added the `admin` prefix to the `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml` resource so your login path (`fos_user_security_login`) would now be at `/admin/login`.

Comment: After almost two hours without nothing to do on the project (I was out having lunch) i tried to have access to **app.dev** and..surprise!! Just started working.

And yes I knew i added admin and works fine, but that was very weird because even trying to have access to app.php Symphony redirected me to app.php/login and saying me about that strange exception.

Anyway, thanks! :)